# Joomla cache_dir and other directories are not writable

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, fedora, joomla

I have a Fedora install running apache and Joomla. The http.conf is showing apache as the user and group that it is using. I have changed the owner of the folder structure using chown -R apache /mywebsitepath

I have even gone so far as in my testing environment to do a chmod -R 777 on the directory to see if that would get me through, with no success. I have restarted httpd services to ensure this has taken effect.

I am able to create blog posts and items that use the database for storage, what am I missing?

Figured it out - selinux was set to enabled. Changed to disabled

Comment: For better help you should post the real paths on your system's document root, and a sanitized joomla conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - selinux was set to enabled. Changed to disabled